# How to convert the float datatype to string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using sql server 2000

Table1

```
id value (float)

001 10.00
002 
003 
004 08.50
...
```

i want to check the value column, if is null then display 'NA'

Tried Query

```
Select id,
CASE WHEN value  IS NULL then '-' else value end  AS value
from table1
```

'

```
Select id,
isnull(value, '-') AS value
from table1
```

Both query showing error as "Error converting data type varchar to float."

How to solve this issue.

need query help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select id, 
isnull(convert(varchar(20),value), '-') AS value 
from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT id, CAST(COALESCE(value, 'NA') as VARCHAR(25)) as [Value]
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

use below query :

```
SELECT id, ISNULL( CAST(value as VARCHAR(25)), 'NA')) as [Value]
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,cast(isnull(value,'') as varchar(10)) from table
```